# spotfire custom expression for scatter plot

Tags: expression, scatter-plot, spotfire

I have this data table:

```
| Name | Val | Month|
| -----| ----| -----|
| A    | 3   | Jan  |
| B    | 2   | Jan  |
| A    | 1   | Feb  |
| B    | 4   | Feb  |
```

and I'd like a scatter plot comparing A's values to B's values by putting all A.Vals on the Y axis and all B.vals on the X axis.
Is there a custom expression I could use for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can with the table as it is, because you would be trying to plot different rows on the X and Y axis. The simplest thing would be to pivot your table, for example like adding this transformation:

Row Identifiers: Month

Column Titles: Name

Values and aggregation methods: None(Val)

Transfer columns: None

You end up with a table with columns Month, (Val) for A, (Val) for B which you can simply plot.